# How to draw grease pencil hidden behind VDBclouds, without being is always at the forefront?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I want to draw something hidden behind VDBclouds, but the Grease Pencil is always at the forefront of the view.

What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*", "*help*", "*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 3):

This is when you use viewlayers.

[image]

Create two collections [Front, Back]

In the Front collection put the Clouds that should be covering the monkey.

In the Back collection put the the monkey and other clouds, and the background image.

[image]

Label the layer front

[image]

Then hide the back.

[image]

Next create a new view layer.

[image]

Call it Back. And hide the front.

[image]

Then enable transparency on the output and set-up your compositor like this.

[image]

Unfortunately you cannot put the monkey INSIDE a volume. You would have to use a gradient to cut the volume in half and render it that way if that was what you wanted

But that's how you do that.